# Nginx alias or rewrite for Horde Groupware ActiveSync URL does not process the rpc.php file

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, activesync

I'm trying to setup a Horde groupware with Nginx. The webinterface works but I do not get the ActiveSync specific URL to work. The Horde Wiki explains how to use it with an Apache Webserver [here](http://wiki.horde.org/ActiveSync).

My problem is, that I setup a rewrite (tried an alias too) to serve the location `/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync` via the `/horde/rpc.php` script. But with my current configuration nginx does the rewrite and returns a 200 status code. But it looks like that the php file is not executed. If I go to `/horde/rpc.php` directly it opens up the login dialog. So this seems to work correct.

Firstly I was googling about the problem but could not find a working solution. So now I would like to ask you.

The configuration should allow to access the ActiveSync part via the URL `/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync`. The horde webinterface is already accessible via `/horde`.

My configuration looks like this:

**default-ssl.conf**

```
server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         /opt/nginx/conf/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /opt/nginx/conf/certs/server.key;
        server_name             example.com;
        index                   index.html index.php;
        root                    /var/www;

        include sites-available/horde.conf;
}
```

**horde.conf**

```
location /horde {
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync(.*)$ /horde/rpc.php$1 last;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /rampage.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include sites-available/horde.fcgi-php.conf;
        }
}
```

**horde.fcgi-php.conf**

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

**fastcgi_params (default nginx)**

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

The nginx log level is set to debug. The output after the request is:

```
2014/06/13 10:33:15 [notice] 17332#0: *1 "^/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync(.*)$" matches "/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync", client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: example.com, request: "GET /horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2014/06/13 10:33:15 [notice] 17332#0: *1 rewritten data: "/horde/rpc.php", args: "", client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: example.com, request: "GET /horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

All this is happening on a RaspberryPi with Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (which is mainly a Debian Wheezy).
So I guess the rewrite works but the php file is not processed?! Does anyone know where the problem is and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
If I change the file `rpc.php` to `mytest.php` with this content:

```
<pre>
<?php var_export( $_SERVER ); ?>
</pre>
```

AND change the rewrite to

```
rewrite ^/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync(.*)$ /horde/mytest.php$1 last;
```

I get the correct output:

```
array (
  'USER' => 'www-data',
  'HOME' => '/var/www',
  'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER',
  'QUERY_STRING' => '',
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => '',
  'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '',
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/horde/mytest.php',
  'REQUEST_URI' => '/horde/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync',
  'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/horde/mytest.php',
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/var/www',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'nginx/1.4.4',
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
  'REMOTE_PORT' => '25330',
  'SERVER_ADDR' => 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
  'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
  'SERVER_NAME' => 'example.com',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
  'PATH_INFO' => '',
  'PATH_TRANSLATED' => '/var/www',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/var/www/horde/mytest.php',
  'HTTP_HOST' => 'example.com',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate',
  'HTTP_DNT' => '1',
  'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'XXX',
  'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE' => 'Thu, 12 Jun 2014 11:56:09 GMT',
  'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0',
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive',
  'PHP_SELF' => '/horde/mytest.php',
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1402664378.2101,
  'REQUEST_TIME' => 1402664378,
)
```

So why is the rpc.php not correctly working? If I understand correctly it tries to establish a basic authentication process. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

After more trying and looking at logs (finally the right ones) I found *my* fault. After all it was a configuration error.

The Horde Wiki gives the hint in one single line:

> To activate the server, it needs to be enabled in Horde's configuration, on the ActiveSync tab.

This one gives me the right direction: I searched in the configuration but could not found the ActiveSync stuff. So I digged deeper and ended up with the awareness that I did not install the library Horder_ActiveSync. :(

After doing a `sudo pear install horde/horde_activesync` and updating the database tables from the WebUI everything works now!

Hope this helps someone else.